# Turn on gps remotely

Tags: android, remote-server

I would like to turn on/off GPS on android mobile remotely via web portal.

I did google for this and found an app already doing this. The app named **real time tracker** is doing this, I tried their app and it worked.

Below are some details about the app mentioned on google play store,

Supports remote start via text message (SMS) or just via the web portal [greenalp.com](http://www.greenalp.com). Its Great for battery saving.

Supports various remote commands you can send via web portal. Ideal for tracking your children or your pets.

**App link:** https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.greenalp.RealtimeTracker

**server link:** [greenalp.com](http://greenalp.com)

Register on there site and then download and login to the application, you can check this feature your self.

My question is how they are able to do this? I know its security concern and android wont allow this. but I am not able to figure out the workaround they are using for it.

If you guys know any workaround please do answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know this would be one of 100 question here but I dint get answer for some question like if we can't programmatically turn on gps then how is this app doing it.

There is "enabled", and there is "on". An app **cannot** make GPS be enabled if the user has disabled it. An app **can** make GPS be on if the GPS was enabled by the user.

This app uses `LocationManager` (or possibly `LocationClient`) to find the device's location, if GPS has been enabled. This app [does not enable GPS that was disabled](http://www.greenalp.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=679).